# How to run bat file on windows server using GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, windows-server

I find many solutions for Linux but how can I run a bat file on a windows server using SSH and GitHub Actions?

Comment: Do you want to do ssh from GitHub action and run bat file

Comment: yes that's what I want to do, but the package from appleboy that I usually use is not working with windows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to SSH into a windows server using Github action then you can utilize [SSH Remote Commands](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-remote-commands). Once successfully logged in you can run the command

Example from [SSH Remote Commands](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-remote-commands)

```yaml
name: remote ssh command
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        script: whoami
```

**A sample GitHub Action will be like this**

```yaml
name: SSH into windows server and run bat file

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    ssh:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - name: SSH into windows server and run bat file
          uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
          with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
          script: |
              cd C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\test
              dir
              test.bat

    # Check if the bat file ran successfully
    check:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: ssh
        steps:
        - name: Check if the bat file ran successfully
          if: ${{ needs.ssh.outputs.exitcode == 0 }}
          run: |
              echo "Check if the bat file ran successfully"
```

Comment: Comment from the Repo: `Important: Only support Linux docker container.`

Comment: The script still runs without errors, but the bat file is not executed.

Comment: @JanBoehmer Can you share debug output of Github action it will be helpful to find problem

Comment: There is no output. it says it ran successfully but it is just skipping the scripts. I think because the package is not meant to be used with windows

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this?